# Populate datatable in C# from GPX file

Tags: c#, datatable, gpx

I will be grateful i someone tells me whether there's a way to import a GPX file into a C# datatable.
I googled it many times but in vain.

Comment: What sort of database are you looking to populate, SQL?

Comment: It's not a database, i just want to **populate a datatable** in order to use these data to create a shapefile

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this would be to deserialise the XML into an object that you could then navigate and use as you wish.

Using the XML data generated from a [Garmin Oregon 400T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) as an example:

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" creator="Oregon 400t" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <link href="http://www.garmin.com">
      <text>Garmin International</text>
    </link>
    <time>2009-10-17T22:58:43Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>Example GPX Document</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>4.46</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:26Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>4.94</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:31Z</time>
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="47.644548" lon="-122.326897">
        <ele>6.87</ele>
        <time>2009-10-17T18:37:34Z</time>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

You could create a few custom classes that could be used for deserialisation of the XML:

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("gpx")]
public class gpx {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("metadata")]
    public Metadata mData { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("trk")]
    public TrackCollection tCollection { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class Metadata {
    /// Fill in metadata elements here
}

[Serializable()]
public class TrackCollection {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("trkseg")]
    [XmlArrayItem("trkpt", typeof(TrackPart))]
    public TrackPart[] tPart { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class TrackPart {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("lat")]
    public double lattitude { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("lon")]
    public double longitude { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ele")]
    public int elapsed { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("time")]
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't double checked this example so please use it with caution. You could alternatively make use of the .NET XML Reader libraries and manually set each of the object properties.

You can also read more about deserialisation of XML [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document#) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part).

Then it is just a case of using your newly created object to populate your `DataTable`. It's up you how you populate your `DataTable`, but you could for example do:

```
gpx myObject = deserialseGPXFile(); // example
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("lat", typeof(double));
table.Columns.Add("lon", typeof(double)); 

foreach (TrackPart tPart in myObject.TrackCollection)
{
    table.Rows.Add(tPart.lattitude, tPart.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still don't understand how to populate a datatable using the extracted data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll  test it

Comment: there is a problem in the declaration of myObject :/

Comment: I'm afraid that you will have to be more specific, code samples would help as well.

Comment: `gpx myObject = deserialseGPXFile();`
the name 'deserialseGPXFile' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @geocoder `deserialiseGPXFile()` was an example of how to call a method (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm). For example, you could to write the code for a method called `deserialiseGPXFile` that would return a `gpx` object. More information on classes and objects here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_classes.htm

Comment: Thank you so much :) 
I used XPath to decode the gpx file and get the needed information.
thanks again

Comment: @geocoder Yes XPath is another way of doing things, glad it all worked out!

Answer (score 0):

this function will help you.
you can modify code according to project need.

```
internal static DataTable ReadGpxFile(string gpxfile)
    {
        AFolderFiles.AFolderFilesPermission.AddFolderSecurity(gpxfile);
        DataTable table = new DataTable("gpxfile");
        table.Columns.Add("ident", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("lat", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("long", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("time", typeof(string));
        XmlDocument gpxDoc = new XmlDocument();
        gpxDoc.Load(gpxfile);
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(gpxDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1");
        XmlNodeList nl = gpxDoc.SelectNodes("//x:trkpt", nsmgr);
        foreach (XmlElement xelement in nl)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
            dataRow[0] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(xelement.GetAttribute("ident")) == true ? "GPXFILE" : xelement.GetAttribute("ident");
            dataRow[1] = xelement.GetAttribute("lat");
            dataRow[2] = xelement.GetAttribute("lon");
            dataRow[3] = xelement.GetAttribute("time");
            table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        return table;
    }
```